# If $M$ and $N/M$ are finitely generated, then so is $N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ and $N$ be $R-$modules, and $$0\longrightarrow M\overset{\iota}{\longrightarrow} N\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} N/M\longrightarrow 0$$ an exact sequence. Let $M$ and $N/M$ finitely generated. Show that $N$ is finitely generated.

I know how to prove it, but I wanted to do as following if it's possible. Since $M$ and $N/M$ are finitely generated, then there is a surjection $$\sigma :R^{\oplus s}\longrightarrow M$$
and a surjection $$\tau : R^{\oplus t}\longrightarrow N/M.$$

What I want to show is that there is a surjection $$R^{\oplus s}\oplus R^{\oplus t}\longrightarrow N.$$
If $$\pi_1:R^{\oplus s}\oplus R^{\oplus t}\longrightarrow R^{\oplus s}$$
and $$\pi_2: R^{\oplus s}\oplus R^{\oplus t}\longrightarrow R^{\oplus t}$$
are the projection, we have that $\sigma \circ \pi_1$ and $\tau\circ \pi_2$ are onto, but ow can I do better ?

Comment: $R^{\oplus t}$ is a projective $R$-module, so you can lift $\tau$ to $\tau' \colon R^{\oplus t} \to N$.

Comment: @Watson: It's not the same question ! I know how to prove it like the link you gave ! I just wanted to use an other technic.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't know what are projective modules

Comment: [A generalisation of free modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module).

Comment: To be fair, it isn't really a different proof, just the same argument dressed up in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

*Snake lemma* or, if not at  your disposal, diagram hunting in
\begin{alignat}{4}
0\longrightarrow R^s&\longrightarrow\, & R^s\oplus R^t &\longrightarrow &R^t~~&\longrightarrow 0 \\
\downarrow~&&\downarrow\quad~&&\downarrow~~\\
0\longrightarrow M &\longrightarrow & N\quad~ &\longrightarrow~ & N/M&\longrightarrow 0 
\end{alignat}

Comment: let be $0\to R^s \to R^s⊕R^t\to R^t\to0$ and $0⟶M⟶N⟶N/M⟶0$ exact sequence and $σ:R^s⟶M$ and $τ:R^t⟶N/M$ then exists module homomorphism $\beta:R^s⊕R^t\to N$, and if $\sigma $ and $τ$ onto or surjective or isomorphism then $\beta$ onto or surjective or isomorphism. if we define $σ:R^s⟶M$ in form $(r_1,...,r_s)\to \sum_{n=1}^s r_ix_i $ then $\sigma$ surjective that $M=(x_1,...,x_s)$ ,then $N$ finitely generated, besides $σ∘π_1$ surjective because $\sigma$,$\pi_1$ are surjective. In same way we prove that $σ∘π_2$ is surjective. if $\sigma$ and $τ$ onto then $\beta$ onto.

Comment: It doesn't prove β is onto.. You really have to do some diagram chasing.